# Htaccess Block Direct access php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added htaccess rules to rewrite url like following...

```
RewriteRule ^demo/$ demo.php [L,QSA]
```

This is working fine for me.
Now issue is i want to block url for demo.php file. Like user can access only

```
www.example.com/demo/ (valid)
www.example.com/demo.php (not valid and want to block this url)
```

Please help me do this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /demo\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This will redirect to 404 page?

Comment: Anubhava, I read many of your posts where you said %{THE_REQUEST} is a secure and safe var, it doesnt loop and doesnt match the 2nd iteration of rewrite rule. but I am just curious Why does it not match the uri on second round of Rule processing?

Comment: It doesn't match in 2nd iteration because `THE_REQUEST` remains unchanged. So even if `REQUEST_URI` becomes `/demo.php` after OP's rewrite rule, `THE_REQUEST` will still be `/demo`

Comment: Anubhava there is something wrong here.

after adding this rules i am not able access any file under /demo directory. it redirect me to 404

Comment: This rule will only block direct requests to `/demo.php`, there might be other rules also.